# Are the real Grassmannians simple spaces?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The real Grassmannians are not simply connected. My question is whether they are simple in the sense that their fundamental group acts trivially on the higher homotopy groups.

Thank you.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ is not simple, but $\mathbb{R}P^{2n+1}$ is.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I even found it as an exercise in Hatcher's book. As a matter of fact my main concern is the real Grassmannian `G(2,4)` of planes in 4-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JHF mentioned, this not even all projective spaces are simple, not to speak about Grassmannians.